# How does apply function work to read all array arguments passed to inner function?

Tags: javascript

below i quote from eloquentJavascript

[Passing along Arguments](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_7/X8BSjdvi)

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}
```

the above works for single argument and i got that part clear but 
what i would like to know is the phrase that comes after regarding `apply`
method...it says we can pass an array-like argument list to the above function....
i tried doing it and failed...
can anyone illustrate how to pass an array-like object of arguments and the function calling the arguments passed?

i saw the call, apply and bind functions from other sites but i would like to stick on this tutorial and see how it works here?

i run the above function as:

```
return noisy(String)(0); //works

return noisy(String).apply(null,[0,1,2,3,4]);
```

gets the same result as above:

`calling with 0
called with 0 - got 0`

how can i use apply to the noisy function to read all arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the bellow snippet**

```js
// Code goes here

function noisy(f) {
      return function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        for(var i=0;i<args.length;i++){
        console.log("calling with", args[i]);       
        var val = f(args[i]);
        console.log("called with", args[i], "- got", val);
        }
      };
    }
     noisy(String)(0); //works
     noisy(String).apply(null,[0,1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet (not on my machine) so on chrome browser i get just `"0"` and here on stack i get below result

`calling with [
  0
]
called with [
  0
] - got 0
calling with [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]
called with [
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
] - got 0`

Comment: val = String(0,1,2,3,4) -- this return "0"

Comment: what is your expected behavior?

Comment: `calling with [
  0
]
called with [
  0
] - got 0

calling with [
  1
]
called with [
  1
] - got 1

calling with [
  2
]
called with [
  2
] - got 2

calling with [
  3
]
called with [
  3
] - got 3

calling with [
  4
]
called with [
  4
] - got 4`

Comment: `var val = f(arg);` -- i get it returns '0', so what is the point in using apply here?

doesnt it have the same effect of one argument?

i was wrecking my head to get my expected behavior (which is wrong, i get it now) using apply for an hour or so....

Comment: thanks..that clears me up...but again opens pandora box for call function and usage....i havent reached to that yet...but we cant use just apply function with array arguments to get my expected behavior right (so that i get it clear without a doubt)?

Comment: instead of call you can replace      var val = f(args[i]);

Comment: wouldn't undefined pop up as error since args is not passed anywhere?

Comment: args is defined based on arguments Object take a look on the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: i know the `arguments` object....but like you said and i quote  with due permission `instead of call you can replace var val = f(args[i]);` 
unquote...do you mean to remove the `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` and just use args directly? wouldnt that pop up undefined error for variable args?

Comment: yes in this case you can use directly , but the arguments object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but does not have any Array properties except length. For example, it does not have the pop method. However it can be converted to a real Array. var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

Comment: i did not mean the `pop up` method but say like pop up of the alert box ( rather old now since console.log is preferred to alert )
so, without call there is no way to list the arguments or pass array of arguments to the function to get my expected behavior.....

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) or the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

The second operator of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) expects an array, but it does not apply the array to your function. Instead it will call it by adding every array item as a parameter.